# 0-12V Adjustable Home Made DC Source not working

Tags: dc, source

I have a **home made dc source** that is made a few years ago. Solders at the back of the board are very bad so I can not track the connections very good. But it's circuit diagram is very similar to the following diagram. 
[image]

Solders of connections of pot was broken off. I connected them randomly. I measured the output, the output voltage is 0 V. I changed the pin connections of pot but the output is still 0V. I did some measurements and saw the output of regulator is 0V while its input is approximately 17-18 V. Is it possible regulator is broken? What can be the reason of 0 volt at the output of the regulator? What can be the reason of 0 volt at the output of dc source?

Comment: "I connected them randomly" - that implies that the circuit you show is probably not what you have before you. That makes the chance of a useful answer quite low, don't you think?

Comment: Are you sure the circuit you describe was originally identical to the schematic you show, or you have posted a random LM317 schematic? `What can be the reason of 0 volt at the output of dc source?` Can you provide more info , have you measured the voltages at pins 1 and 3 of LM317?

Comment: @alexan_e I checked the circuit and see it's very similar to above schematic the differences are: it has a transistor and it has two diodes I think they are for half wave rectification. Solders at the back of the board are so bad, I couldn't track the connections very good.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen you are right, but solders at the back of the board are very bad so I couldn't track connections very good. But the circuit is very similar to schematic in the question. I checked it as I can.

Comment: @alexan_e I checked the connections, the output of the whole circuit and outout of lm317 are connected to each other. Pins 1 and 3 of lm317 have approximately 17.5 volt.

Comment: It's probably like [this](http://ourlibro.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/lm317-linear-power-suply-with-current-bosster1.gif). Is the transistor a PNP? Can you remove it and see if you get an output from LM317?

Comment: @alexan_e Transistor is BC1408B, it is an npn transistor. Are you sure about removing it?

Comment: Removing it is not going to damage anything(there is no device connected in the output I suppose), remove it and measure the LM317 output. Maybe your circuit is like [this](http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele/img/lm317.gif)? I can't find a BC1408 datasheet but BC are low power devices, doesn't make sense to be used as an output transistor.

Comment: You know, it would be much easier and faster to just make the circuit from scratch rather than trying to troubleshoot the existing one (especially when based on speculations about the actual circuit).

Comment: @alexan_e I removed the transistor still there is no any voltage at output of lm317.(0 volt) You are right maybe designing and realizing it again would be better than trying to  fix  the existing one.

Comment: See addition to my answer and comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ABOUT 18V on LM317 input:

- Short ALL 3 pot connections together.
  You should get about 1.2V output.

If not 1.2V check LM317 input.

- **If** LM317 input is ~= 18V and all pot pins are shorted and Vout not ~= 1.2V the LM317 is dead.
- **If** LM317 input is loaded down to << 18V something is wrong with cct shown.

If LM317 output is ~= 1.2V then

Turn pot to half position.
Measure resistance between pins AB BC CA
One pin will measure ~= 5k/2 to other two.
Two pins will measure 5k between them (if 5k pot) 
~= half R pin is wiper.

Connect one end pin to known cct ground.
Connect wiper pin with pot set to half setting to each of 3 pot pins on PCB in turn.

When wiper is on correct pin Vout will be ABOUT (2500 + 220)/ 220 * 1.2 = ABOUT 15V.
As pot may ne lin or log or ??? mid point may not be half Resistance position so Vout may be in 10-16V range probably.

You now know wiper pin.
Either of end pins can go to either of the remaining two positions.
Swapping them reverse rotation direction for increasing voltage.

**If** this is now not working there is something else wrong with your circuit.

---

**Added:**

Take a BARE LM317.
Put a cap at Vin and Vout (anything - 1 uF, 100 uF,...)
Ground ref terminal.
Put 220R from Vout to ref (this is essential).
Apply 18V to Vin.
Measure Vout.
If it is not ~~~= 1.2 V rejig brain and try again.

Comment: Finally I got voltage at the output of the circuit but it is in the range 0 to 3.4 V. How can amplify it in to range of 0-12V? Should I use a power transistor?

Comment: You should follow the instructions that I provided and report the results. The circuitry that you have now is entirely capable of doing what you want without you running off on new tangents. People cannot provide you with good quality assistance if you do not do your part and accurately report back what you do and what happened. Did you follow my instructions? What DID you do?

Comment: I shorted all 3 pot connections together and got 0 volt at pin 2 of lm317. You are saying LM317 is dead if it is how can I have 0 to 3.4 volts when I shorted `2` pot connections together?

Comment: @ScienceEnthusiast My analysis stands. IF your cct is about as shown then if you did what I said and there was ~18V in you'd get about 1.2V out if the LM317 is alive and the output not shorted or overloaded. What I did effectively grounds pin 1 of LM317 (or should if your pot is connected to it as it should be. ) | So - NO intention to be rude. This is what logical deduction shows: Your LM317 is dead OR your cct scrambled beyond what you show or you are measuring in the wrong place or measuring wrongly. Try the following ...

Comment: ... Take a BARE LM317. Put a cap at in and out (anything - 1 uF, 100 uF,...) Ground ref terminal. Put 220R from Vout to ref (this is essential). Apply 18V to Vin. Measure Vout. If it is not ~~~= 1.2 V rejig brain and try again.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the circuit is now working and output is in the range of 0 to 13.6 volts. Seriously thanks you gave me a very detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

This circuit should produce about 27 Volts of output voltage provided enough input voltage. It also should not be able to regulate down to 0 Volts at all.
Please check your potentiometer resistance and output connection.